# How to remove the 2nd element of every tuple in a list of 3-ples?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, parsing, data-structures

I have a big list like this:

```
list__=[('string id1', 'string id2', 'string id3'), ('string id4', 'string id5', 'string id6'), ... ,('string idn', 'string id', 'string idn-1')]
```

How can I drop the ids from this big tuple, for example:

```
[('string', 'string', 'string'), ('string', 'string', 'string'), ... ,('string', 'string', 'string')]
```

Any idea of how can I aproach this?. I tried with:

```
OutputTuple = [(a, b, d) for a, b, c, d in ListTuple]
```

But it just drop the second element.

Comment: Simply split each item and get the item at first(0th) index: `[tuple(y.split()[0] for y in x) for x in list__]`

Comment: what characters are in the string id's?

Comment: very large keys I dont think with a regex I could solve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
my_list = [tuple([j.split()[0] for j in i]) for i in my_list]
```

Comment: i think this answer is the best way to do.

Answer (score 1):

Unpacking will be more efficient than using a double for loop:

```
[(a.split()[0], b.split()[0], c.split()[0]) for a, b, c in  list__ ]
```

You could also index to the whitespace:

```
  [(a[:a.index(" ")], b[:b.(" ")], c[:c.index(" ")]) for a,b,c in  list__ ]
```

Interestingly using `str.find` is the most efficient solution using python2.7.

```
In [41]: timeit [(a[:a.find(" ")], b[:b.find(" ")], c[:c.find(" ")]) for a,b,c in  list__ ]
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.27 µs per loop

In [42]: timeit [tuple([j.split()[0] for j in i]) for i in list__]
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.85 µs per loop

In [43]: timeit [(a.split()[0], b.split()[0], c.split()[0]) for a, b, c in  list__ ]
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.73 µs per loop
```